# How I make a list of documents with mongoose? (Schema)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I don't know how to make a list of documents with mongoose (Node JS), someone know's how to make that?

```
new mongoose.Schema({
   first_name: String,
   last_name: String,
   companies: [
      {
         name_company:String,
         post:String,
         time_in_post:String,
      }     

   ] 
});
```

I need to insert many documents with companies schema at different times but I don't know how to make that with mongoose.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is wrong with what you have implemented? That seems correct. I would add that you could make 2 different schema's and have them reference each other so that you don't duplicate unnecessarily.. i.e. User schema and Company schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like splitting this into different schemas might be a good idea. Especially if other people will be apart of the same company.

For instance, maybe you could try this:

```js
const CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    // ... other company specific attributes
});

const Company = mongoose.model("Company", CompanySchema);

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    companies: [
        {
            company: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company' },
            post: String,
            timeInPost: String,
        }
    ]
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

And the interaction with the models could look like this:

```js
(async () => {
    try {
        const company1 = await Company.create({ name: "Company 1" });
        const company2 = await Company.create({ name: "Company 2" });

        const user1 = await User.create({
            firstName: "first",
            lastName: "last",
            companies: [
                {
                    company: company1._id,
                    post: "....",
                    timeInPost: "....",
                },
                {
                    company: company2._id,
                    post: "....",
                    timeInPost: "....",
                },
            ],
        });

        const users = await User.find({}).populate("companies.company"); // in order to populate the company with the document from the company collection

        // users with companies info
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
```

Referenced from the mongoose documentation: https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-referencing-schema-in-properties-and-arrays/

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach, with this way you avoid data duplication:

```
const companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name_company: String,
  post: String,
  time_in_post: String
});

new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  companies: [companySchema] // Array of subdocuments
});
```

See full documentation here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html